# Sign up for Power BI Service with organizational user from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I follow the tutorial from website to create new Azure AD tenant and create organizational user for this new tenant:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-create-an-azure-active-directory-tenant/

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-sign-up-for-power-bi-service/

[image]

But when I use this new user  to sign up Power BI service, I get the error as below, how to overcome this?

[image]

Comment: I accidentally saw a tutorial mentioning your problem, hope it can help you: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-self-service-signup-for-power-bi/, https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-syndication-partner/

Answer (score 0):

I have a try following the tutorial, it has no problem. There is one step `Add a user to your Azure Active Directory tenant`, make sure your Azure Active Directory tenant can manage subscription, it is a co-administrator.

Comment: Please could you elaborate more "your Azure Active Directory tenant can manage subscription", I am not sure that I understand this

Comment: I will explain it later. Firstly, I want to confirm if the user format you created is {user name}@{Azure_AD_Name}.onmicrosoft.com ?

Comment: Yes, if you take a look the image, I have followed the format

Comment: Do we really need Office 365 subscription in order to make it works?

Comment: sorry, when I used this user I created to sign up Power BI service,it prompted update your password, I thought I login successfully. Actually it was not, the new page is " Great! Go check your email.
To finish signing up, click the link in the mail from Office 365 ". So far, I dont know the mail address to open **@***.onmicrosoft.com. when I use the this user I created to login office 365, I cant find mail feature.

Comment: "your Azure Active Directory tenant can manage subscription" means your account is a administrator or a co-administrator, its cause is not here.